# How to prevent package updation in `apt-get install -y package` if the package is already installed?

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation

`apt-get install -y packagename` update the package if it's already installed. How can I prevent this? I don't want to update the package if it's already installed. What switch is to be used with apt-get for this ? I have checked the man pages , But I couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`man apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt-get.8):

```
   --no-upgrade
       Do not upgrade packages; when used in conjunction with install,
       no-upgrade will prevent packages on the command line from being
       upgraded if they are already installed. Configuration Item:
       APT::Get::Upgrade.
```